# How to tell the logic like plus sign with OR in solr

Tags: solr

All:

Right now, I want to input a search in SOLR like this:

```
+keyword1 OR +keyword2
+keyword1 OR keyword2
```

Could anyone explain how SOLR process this logic?
I am not sure if this above eaquals

```
keyword1 AND keyword2
keyword1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend mixing the prefix (+,-) syntax with the boolean (AND, OR) syntax. "+" corresponds to `Occur.MUST`. A term without a prefix corresponds to `Occur.SHOULD`, which means it gets a scoring boost, but documents lacking that term may be in the results.

I recommend reading this article:
https://lucidworks.com/post/why-not-and-or-and-not/

Comment: Thanks, not fully understand what your answer means(it is my fault, not the answer's), but I feel this is correct answer direction for my confuse. I will study on that link. Could you talk a little detail about how SOLR process the logic combination in query? A procedure diagram and Wenn diagram will be great appreciated

Comment: I read that link, it talks how to think the mapping of prefix and logic operator, but it does not talk how Solr/Lucene parse the query, can to seperate a query in to this structure. For example, if I simply input a keyword, the query parse know it is a MUST, but when I input keyword1[space]keyword2, the parse knows it should be OR. And some example like +keyword1[space]+keyword2, the solr know this is  keyword1 AND keyword2 even there is space which may mean OR. Could you help me with this by talking about the general rule the solr/lucene use when parsing a query? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's a little messy. I think the important part from that article is that it is all MUST, SHOULD, and NOT at the lowest level, so the boolean implementation is a little loose in order to accommodate that.

Comment: this link https://lucidworks.com/blog/why-not-and-or-and-not/ is broken.